# how to assign an value from javascript variable to hidden field

Tags: asp.net, javascript

function(sender, e)   
      {   var **Sessioninfo**= $get('');  
    }

here  from my master page hiiden  field i am getting the value in  **Sessioninfo**

now in child page i have  another hidden field called **hfchildpage**
 now i need  to  assign the Sessioninfo. value  to  hfchildpage

can u plz  provide the  syntax  for it 
 thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends where your control is situated in your page.  FindControl method will not simply find a control anywhere. i.e. It the control may not be found if the control is nested within another control, one needs to step down through the control structure.

However if the resulting element is named 'ct100_hfchildpage' then this bastardized javascript may do what you are looking for.

```
var hfchildpageElement = $get('<%=((Hiddenfield)this.Master.FindControl("ct100_hfchildpage")).ClientID %>');

if(hfchildpageElement) hfchildpageElement.value = 'whatEverYouWant';
```

That said, I think you should review your code and method of using sessions.  Sessions are available server side, they are held server side, and hence not only is it very unusual to be storing and using them via JavaScript on the client side, it is bad practice and may be extremely insecure.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood what you mean...
Set the hidden input the id attribute of **hfchildpage** and use the following:

```
document.getElementById('hfchildpage').value = **the value you want**
```

Comment: tried  the above method but still 'hfchildpage' value  in null